Are there any ahadith about how Umar Ibn Al Khattab treated or interracted with his father after accepting Islam?
I have only come across the hadith where Umar ibn al Kattab references his father's cruelty. If a parent is cruel what was advised at the time of the prophet(Saw)?

His father had died before that.
